# Angular deselect all options in multiple select

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**Goal** is that, when I call *myMethod()*, I want to have all options unselected.

**Currently** when I call *myMethod()* it will deselect only the last option, but the other remain selected if they have been selected.

**Solutions:**

- Not using reactive forms - do it like in the accepted answer
- Using reactive forms - `this.formName.get('formControlName').setValue([]);`

**HTML**

```
<select multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" 
            value="{{user.id}}" 
            [selected]="usersSelected">{{user.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
usersSelected: boolean = false;

myMethod(): void {
    this.usersSelected = false;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please share a working code on stackblitz

Comment: Hmm, see? There are not lazy people like you, who can't make this easy code in stackblitz by themselves. So please stop saying this type of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` so you can control the value. Note that its `multiple` select, so you should use array, not just scalar value.

```
usersSelected = [];

myMethod(): void {
  this.usersSelected = [];
}
```

And in your template:

```
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="usersSelected">
  <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.id">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9y1jm

Comment: The thing I should also say, that im using it with a reactive form directive, so it works for now but it won't work in angular v7, as stated in the documentation "Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7", but found another way, see updated post.

Comment: But it helped me to find the way how to deal with this. so thank you so much!